# How can I login to this website using urllib and urllib2

Tags: python, request, urllib2, encode, urllib

```
url : https://myaccount.adlkerala.com/login.php
```

**page source:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Mettle-Wire Login</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        @import "/mettle.css";
    </style>
</head>
<body style="background-color: #fff;">
<div align="center">
<form method="post">
<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="3">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;">
        <br>
        <div id="clientlogo-center"></div>
        <br>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center"><b>Login</b></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Username</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="username" value=""></td>
    <tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Password</td>
        <td><input type="password" name="pass"></td>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Login"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
</div> <!--container-->

<div id="logofooter"><a href="http://www.mettlenetworks.com/products/mettlewire.html?mwa"><span id="logo"><img src="images/g64m.png" alt="METTLE Wire" style="border:none;"></span></a> ver. 1.9.&nbsp;&copy;&nbsp;Mettle Networks</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

'Encoding and requesting' methods (still learning), as normally used, doesn't seem to be working here. How do I submit the data and login?
Btw, this webpage logs in to the 'personal account' page of my ISP.

Comment: Make a POST request to whereever the form is POSTing to, so `https://myaccount.adlkerala.com/login.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should download the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) package.

Assuming **@TankorSmash** found the right POST URL:

```
import requests

# set username and password here
username = <username>
password = <password>
s = requests.session()
r = s.post('https://myaccount.adlkerala.com/login.php', data={'username': username, 'pass': password})
```

Now, the `s` session object should be logged in, and you can move forward from there.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to look into a "post" rather than a "get", it might be helpful to look at the `requests` package, which will fairly easily do posts and gets

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/